# Number of bits set for 3*num, having a list o set bit positions for num

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have an array containing indexes of set bits for a really big number (up to 10000 bits, which can't be represented with primitive types). Example: array: [0, 2, 3, 6, 10] corresponds to 10001001101.

In other words: num = pow(A[0]) + pow(A[1]) + .... + pow(A[n-1]), where pow(x) = 2<sup>x</sup>.

Suppose now that you have a number K = 3 * num.

How to find the number of bits set in K ?

I believe it is possible to do it in O(n), where n is the number of elements in the array.

My idea is to iterate through the items in the array, simulating an add between the number and itself shifted 1 position to the left. However I couldn't find a clean logic for it.

Comment: IMO your intuition is correct: work from right (LSB) to left (MSB), while adding the carry.

Comment: That was exactly my idea, however it gets a bit tricky. Consider the number 5 - array is [0, 2]. You should get 4 as a result. Then consider 7 - array is [0, 1, 2], which results in 3.

Comment: I would like clarification. If num=5 (arr5=[0,2], is 3*5=15 (arr15=[0,1,2,3]) what you wish?

Comment: I don't really need the array15. Just the number of elements in it, that would mean the number of set bits in it = 4. Got it?

Comment: You have (non-zero length) runs of ones separated by runs of zeroes. _If_ separated by at least two zeroes: for each single one, there will be two in the result; for each longer run of ones, there will be just as many as before. It only gets murky when ones are separated by a single zero…

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll think about it a little better. :)

Comment: While you're at it (in the loop) you can keep count of the number of set `1` bits.

Comment: Please specify whether the indices are in ascending order.

Comment: popcount(3*_num_) <= 2*_n_, and at least 2 for 0 < _n_ (& _num_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from LSB to MSB, you have *runs* of set bits separated by runs of cleared bits: *gaps*.
(Without a *carry in*,) Each single `1` will turn into `11` - the "more significant `1`" in a place where there was a zero before: no *carry out*.
If you prepend `10` to a longer run of `1`s and clear the least-significant-but-one bit, you get the binary representation of three times the original number - with exactly the same number of bits set. And a `1` where there *might* be the next, err, one as well as `1`: a *carry out*. Any *carry in* gets absorbed: it just "exchanges" both least significant bits.
With the `11` that represents three times a single `1`, a *carry in* causes a *carry out* - and clears two bits (try with `101011` * 3).
Gaps longer than one "absorb" carries.
Assume input indices in ascending order, presort, or surprise me with an *O(n)* algorithm. I'd be tempted to code a state machine using labels.
As I'm practising python:

```
def popcount3num(indices):
    '''
    given, in (strictly) ascending order, the indices of bits set
     in the binary representation of a natural number num,
     return the number of bits set in 3*num
    '''
    prev = -3           # position of last bit handled
    count = carry = 0   # carry is for bitposition handled + 2
    for i in indices:
    #   print(i, count, carry)
        if prev == i-1:     # in a run of set bits
            if not carry:
                carry = 1   # "move bit from count to carry"
                count -= 1
            else:
                count += 1  # tally
        else:               # gap
            if not carry:
            # without a carry in, every run produces
            #  two bits at least, including carry out
                count += 2
            elif prev < i-2:
            # if the carry was for a lower position, just tally
                count += 3
                carry = 0
            else:
            # with a carry in, a lone one will change nothing
            # a run will add just as many as without carry
                pass
        prev = i
    return count + carry
```

Comment: The place I saw the challenge suggests it is simpler than this. It doesn't provide a solution, but says O(n) runtime, O(1) space.

Comment: @Marcus: Given indices in ascending order, this _is O(n)_ (and simple, at least sort of). With indices in arbitrary order (you don't specify in revision 1 of this question), I'd be surprised if there _was_ a way to determine the number of bits set in _3*num_ in _o(n)_.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks a lot and sorry about the long delay to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

From this test:

[image]

I observe:

1. If sizeof(arrN)==1, then sizeof(arrRes)=2
2. If 'v' exists in both arrN and arr2N, then eliminate it and repeat with 'v+1' until 'v+x' doesn't exist or is last value. Then increase that 'v+x'.
   Example N=3: '1' exists in boths, eliminate; '2' only in one, but is last; increment '2'.
3. After applying 2) if a value exists in arrN, but not in arr2N then it will exists in arrRes, size will be ++1. Same for a value in arr2N and not in arrN. Example N=9.

N=11 is a complex example. Detail:

1. '0' in arrN, not in arr2N, so put in arrRes.
2. '1' in both; skip '1' and test 1+1=2.
3. '2' in both (well, really only in arr2N, we built the fake '2' from
   the other arr), skip and test '3'.
4. '3' built in arr2N exists in arrN. Skip and test '4'.
5. '4' exist an is the last. Increase it.
6. Final result [0,5]: '0' from step 1 and '5' from step 5

Comment: For the general case res= num1 * num2, I believe an O(n) algorithm can be found, because num1= some shifts (which only increase values in arrNum2) and + num1 (in case !=0) works with my observations.

Comment: Your approach seems to work. But I still think it is possible to do it in O(n) runtime and O(1) space.

Comment: Let me ask, why do you need such complicated task? I would slice a big binary representation into small, say 32 bits, chunks. Sum and multiplication can be defined in terms of these small chuncks, much faster than using arrays.

Comment: @Ripi2: `why [carry out] such complicated task?` obtaining the result manipulating bit indices may be faster than even creating that `big binary representation`.

Comment: Although your solution probably works, there is a better way to do it. Check greybeard's solution. Even though, thanks for your answer.